# More efficient way for calculating margin percent given cost price, unit price, and tax information

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I am trying to come up with a better way to calculate margin percent when given cost price, unit price (selling price), and tax information.

The below code works; but is is NOT efficient in any way. It just loops through all the margin percents from -100 --> 1000 percent and when the solution is found it stops looking and breaks out of loop.

My goal is to not have a long running loop and instead calculate it directly instead of trial by error. The reason it is so tricky is because of the way taxes are setup. It is NOT just a straight percent. See comments for information on how tax is calculated. (Cumulative tax)

```
var cost_price = 100;
var unit_price = 133.10;

//Loop over -100 -> 1000 percent at .01 intervals to try to find margin percent...Not very good
for(var k=-100;k<1000;k+=.01)
{
    var margin_percent = k;
    var marked_up_price_before_tax = cost_price * (1+(margin_percent/100));

    //First tax is 10%...This value is dynamic...could be a different percent
    var first_tax = (marked_up_price_before_tax*(10/100));

    //Second tax is 10% cumulative...This value is dynamic.. Could be a different percent
    var second_tax = (marked_up_price_before_tax + first_tax) *10/100);

    var margin_price = marked_up_price_before_tax + first_tax + second_tax;

   //Make 2 decimals for comparison purposes
    margin_price = parseFloat(Math.round(margin_price * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);

    if (margin_price == unit_price)
    {
       //FOUND IT!
        margin_percent = parseFloat(k);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question shouldn't be a riddle. Provide the details in an organized, well defined manner, not as random meaningless comments within arbitrary code.

Comment: I am not sure how I can explain this better. I stripped out all the unnecessary code and am showing the code the best way I know. I am looping through -100 percent --> 1000 percent in an attempt to find the margin percent.

Comment: Then maybe read [ask].

Comment: should be a simple one line calculation....why all the looping?

Comment: Yes. This is really just an algebra problem; no need to approximate.

Comment: I have the looping because taxes are dynamic (they can change). I cannot figure out how to come up with the equation to solve this.

Comment: p&l = total - (cost+tax) ... where's the dynamic part?

Comment: first tax and second tax are dynamic. In the example I have removed the dynamic nature of it. It is NOT always 10% and can change based on user input. Also tax is a percent

Comment: of course it's a percent...calculate tax add cost subtract from total...not complicated

Comment: In your edit, using the formula @SMcCrohan gave, you have calculated the markup *fraction* 1.099999999 ~ 1.10. This corresponds to a 10% markup, as you require. If you'd like to convert the final result into a percentage, the formula is `(unit_price / (cost_price * tax_1 * tax_2) - 1) * 100`

Comment: Thanks @IgorRaush that did it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two solutions here - one is the algebra that solves the problem you're actually presenting (because estimation isn't required here), and the other is the code for doing the estimating if it WERE required.

**Algebra:**

If we express the markup rate and both tax rates as `1 + increase%`, it makes our math easier. That is, for a markup of 50%, think of that as a multiplier of 1.5; for a tax rate of 10%, think of that as a multiplier of 1.1. Counted that way, your equation is:

`unit_price = cost * markup * tax1 * tax2`

Because we're multiplying here and they're both percentage increases, the order we apply the tax doesn't actually matter...in fact, the fact that the second tax includes the first tax in its taxable amount makes our math EASIER.

Solving for `markup`, that comes out to:

`markup = unit_price / (cost * tax1 * tax2)`

**Code:**

Now, the code for doing this sort of estimation - which is interesting, even though this problem doesn't require it. This problem has some useful traits:

- You can look at a potential answer and not only tell if it's right, but you can tell if it's too high or too low
- The values are continuous
- The values are proportional to your input, even if the proportion changes

Given those, you can solve this with a recursive binary search through the space of reasonable values, and perform FAR fewer comparisons than a linear search.

I'd do something like this:

```
var cost_price = 100;
var unit_price = 130;
var tax_rate_1 = 1.1;
var tax_rate_2 = 1.1;

function estimateMarkup(minMarkup, maxMarkup) {
    if (maxMarkup - minMarkup < 0.001) return null;

    let markup = (minMarkup + maxMarkup) / 2
    let markedupPrice = cost_price * markup * tax_rate_1 * tax_rate_2;

    if (Math.round(markedupPrice) == Math.round(unit_price))
        return markup;

    if (Math.round(markedupPrice) > Math.round(unit_price))
        return estimateMarkup(minMarkup,markup);

    if (Math.round(markedupPrice) < Math.round(unit_price))
        return estimateMarkup(markup,maxMarkup);
}

console.log(estimateMarkup(-100,100))
```

Comment: I don't think I explained how tax 2 percent works. Lets say the price is `100` and the 1st tax rate is `10%` and the 2nd tax rate is `10%`. This means the first tax is `10.00` and the 2nd tax is `11.00` (110 * .1) for a total is `121.00`. This is the part that is making it tricky.

Comment: @ChrisMuench I understood. 100 * 1.1 * 1.1 = 121

Comment: I tried the formula as you setup and I am not getting the right value as I did before. I have edited my question to have an example of what I tried.